# Why docker container acts differently?

Tags: docker

As I understood c120809b91b5 == ubuntu

```sh
[dev@fedora ~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED       STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
c120809b91b5   ubuntu    "bash"    11 days ago   Up 39 minutes             ubuntuContainer

[dev@fedora ~]$ docker run -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ubuntu bash
root@c760c5696300:/# cd testfolder
bash: cd: testfolder: No such file or directory
```

but why they not similar?

```sh
[dev@fedora ~]$ docker exec -it c120809b91b5 bash
(base) root@c120809b91b5:/# cd testfolder
(base) root@c120809b91b5:/testfolder#
```

What I do wrong?

I need to run **c120809b91b5** container with `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` but can't because **ubuntu** container acts like another with another internal environment.

Comment: How did you run `ubuntuContainer`?

Comment: You've launched two _containers_ (with separate filesystems) off of the same `ubuntu` _image_.  If you need to change `docker run` options like `--add-host`, you need to delete and recreate the existing container.  (...which is a good reason to minimize how much you use `docker exec`; write a Dockerfile to do things like set up the filesystem and run that image instead of `ubuntu`.)

Comment: @DavidMaze can I delete one of the versions and make second as actual?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "actual".  A container runs one process and exits, and you can multiple containers running the same image in the same way you can have multiple processes running the same binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that with `docker run` you are creating a new container from the ubuntu image. So when you run `docker run -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ubuntu bash` you are just creating a new container from the ubuntu image which is given a new containerId: c760c5696300

If you run `docker ps -a` you will see that you now have two containers with containerIds c120809b91b5 and c760c5696300

Please read docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 1):

try adding "detached"

```
docker run -d -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ubuntu bash
```

and then look at the result.

I hope it helps.
You probably have some exited docker containers by now look at them with:

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @dacruz

[dev@fedora ~]$ docker run -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway "ubuntuContainer" bash
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.

[dev@fedora ~]$ docker run -it --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway "ubuntucontainer" bash
Unable to find image 'ubuntucontainer:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ubuntucontainer, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.